# A single word for instrument-playing?

Tags: single-word-requests

For eg., Tiya secured first place in singing/dancing/drawing.

How do we say it if Tiya secured first in playing an instrument? Is there any word for *instrument-playing*?

Comment: Answers in comments have been removed, lest this question remain unanswered. **Do not answer in comments:** you deserve real upvotes (and perhaps downvotes) for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just be specific: "Tiya secured first place in violin." But some words may require "the."

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't a word specifically for "performing on a musical instrument," that precludes singing, and that distinguishes performance from other instrumental studies. You can get the closest with two words:

> Tiya secured first place in **instrumental performance**.